# If a mapping and it's inverse are both one to one, then must the mapping be bijective?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

If $\sigma$: $A$ $\rightarrow$ $B$ was a mapping which was one to one, and had an inverse $\sigma$$^{-1}$: $B$ $\rightarrow$ $A$ which is also one to one, then are they both bijective mappings? 
I'm almost certain that this is true, and is pretty much just a different way of saying the mapping is bijective, but I'm a bit ill at the moment and so I don't trust my brain too much on this.

Comment: In fact, assuming by inverse you mean a two sided inverse (both $\sigma\sigma^{-1}$ and $\sigma^{-1}\sigma$ being the appropriate identity) the existence of such an inverse *implies* that $\sigma$ is one-to-one and onto.

Answer (score 0):

If $\sigma^{-1}$ is defined on all of $B$, this means that $\sigma$ is onto too. Hence, $\sigma$ is a bijection. Inverses of bijections are also bijections.

Comment: Yes, I thought so, I just for some reason had a nagging suspicion that that wasn't the same as sigma being onto...I know that the question was simple, but I couldn't let that suspicion go

Comment: If $\sigma $ wasn't onto, we would only have $\sigma^{-1}: \mathrm{Im}(\sigma) \to A$.

Comment: I know, that was the exact same logic I was using, it's just that right now with my head pounding so much I could say 2+2=4 and still not believe it

Answer (score 0):

Let $\sigma \subseteq A \times B$.  Suppose $\sigma$ is 1-1 in the sense: for every $a$ there is at most one $b$ with $(a,b) \in \sigma$; and suppose $\sigma^{-1}$ is 1-1 in the sense: for every $b$ there is at most one $a$ with $(a,b) \in \sigma$.  Then $\sigma$ is a bijection from the domain of $\sigma$ to the range of $\sigma$.